# How in H2DB get sql dump like in MySql?

Tags: sql, h2, dump

I have H2DB database which stores data in files. I have 3 files: `test.18.log.db`, `test.data.db`, and `test.index.db`.

I want get SQL dump file like when I use `mysqldump`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 187):

Yes, there are multiple solutions. One is to run the [SCRIPT SQL statement](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#script):

```
SCRIPT TO 'fileName'
```

Another is to use the [Script tool](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Script.html#main_String...):

```
java org.h2.tools.Script -url <url> -user <user> -password <password>
```

Then, there are also the [RUNSCRIPT statement](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#runscript) and RunScript tool.

By the way, you should consider upgrading to a more recent version of H2. With newer versions, the two files .data.db and .index.db are combined in to a .h2.db file.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. You really should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Maybe one should also ask the question about the restore, not only the backup ;-)

Comment: @ThomasMueller why `SCRIPT TO 'filename'` creates only schema-related queries, not insert queries?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk by default it creates `insert` statements as well, but you can disable that (see the docs).

Comment: How to restore the db, also answered by @Thomas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675768/executing-script-file-in-h2-database/10679673

Answer (score 13):

If you want to get **schema** and **data,** you can use

```
SCRIPT TO 'dump.sql';
```

If you want to get only **schema**, you can use

```
SCRIPT SIMPLE TO 'dump.txt';
```

Comment: I have used `SCRIPT SIMPLE` and it also export data. As per documentation (https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#script), the difference is that "SIMPLE does not use multi-row insert statements.".

Answer (score 4):

Your shortcut:

```
$ ls
foo.mv.db

$ wget -O h2.jar https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/h2database/h2/1.4.200/h2-1.4.200.jar

$ ls
foo.mv.db
h2.jar

$ java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url "jdbc:h2:file:./foo" -user sa -password ""

$ ls
backup.sql
foo.mv.db
h2.jar

$ cat backup.sql | head -n 20
;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS "SA" SALT 'bbe17...redacted...' HASH 'a24b84f1fe898...redacted...' ADMIN;
CREATE SEQUENCE "PUBLIC"."HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" START WITH 145;
CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."...redacted..."(
    "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL SELECTIVITY 100,
    [...redacted...]
    "...redacted..." VARCHAR(255) SELECTIVITY 100
);
ALTER TABLE "PUBLIC"."...redacted..." ADD CONSTRAINT "PUBLIC"."CONSTRAINT_8" PRIMARY KEY("ID");
-- 102 +/- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PUBLIC.[...redacted...];
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."...redacted..." VALUES
([...redacted...]),
```