# Executing script file in h2 database

Tags: h2, sql-scripts

First of all I would like to say am new to h2 database. I need to execute a sql script file in h2 database. I have a script file test.sql and I want to execute this in h2 database. Is it possible?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use the [RUNSCRIPT SQL statement](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#runscript):

```
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'test.sql'
```

or you can use the [RunScript standalone / command line tool](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/RunScript.html):

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/test -script test.sql
```

You can also use the RunScript tool within an application:

```
RunScript.execute(conn, new FileReader("test.sql"));
```

Comment: Is there a trick to using your first example? I have a `bootstrap.sql` that contains nothing but  `RUNSCRIPT FROM 'test.sql'`and my test.sql is a sibling to the bootstrap file. 

If I run `jdbc:h2:mem:etsnom;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'C:/workspace/bootstrap.sql'`, I get a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: If we use, 2nd method of Thomas to create database, then default username and password will be set i.e. "" [empty string]. which is what implemented in "RunScript' class.

However, It is always very important to set username and password to access database, and doing so in case H2 database, we can run below command,

java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/test -user sa -password sa -script test.sql

Answer (score 19):

If you are using spring-boot and spring-test with H2 it will automatically look for `schema.sql` and `data.sql` in your class path and attempt to run these.  So if you put them in `src/test/resources` they should be picked up and run automatically

In addition you can specify the data files you want to run with properties.  For example adding a property to your`application.properties` like

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:users.sql, classpath:books.sql, classpath:reviews.sql
```

will configure spring to run those three sql files instead of running `data.sql`

Answer (score 12):

On OSX (this shouldn't really matter) with v. 1.4.192 with the following commands, no matter what I did I could not see any results:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url "jdbc:h2:file:~/testdb" -user someusername -password somepass -script select.sql
```

where select.sql had simply:

```
select * from PUBLIC.MYTABLE;
```

I had to add the `-showResults` before output began appearing. Here is the complete command:

```
java -cp /Users/az/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.192/h2-1.4.192.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url "jdbc:h2:file:~/testdb" -user someusername -password somepass -script select.sql -showResults
```

If you do not have the needed jar, download from [***here***](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.h2database%22%20AND%20a%3A%22h2%22) (Click on the `jar` links next to each version). Some direct links to the jars are as follows:

[***1.4.193***](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/h2database/h2/1.4.193/h2-1.4.193.jar)  <sup>(Updated 31-Oct-2016)</sup> 
[***1.4.192***](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/h2database/h2/1.4.192/h2-1.4.192.jar)  <sup>(Updated 26-May-2016)</sup> 
[***1.4.191***](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/h2database/h2/1.4.191/h2-1.4.191.jar)  <sup>(Updated 21-Jan-2016)</sup> 
[***1.4.190***](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.jar)  <sup>(Updated 11-Oct-2016)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Use `java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -?` to display available options. However, I haven't been able to find a documentation that explains these in more detail. For example, option `[-checkResults]  Check if the query results match the expected results` sounds interesting, but I couldn't find an explanation how to provide expected results.

Answer (score 2):

For me the system responded with:

> didn't find org.h2.tools.RunScript driver

The solution was:

```
java -classpath <path_to_your_h2-*.jar> org.h2.tools.RunScript \
-url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test -script test.sql
```

See: http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server