# SQL State : 90057, Message : Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (USERNAME)" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: database, spring-boot, h2

I am using h2 in memory DB, I have small spring boot application.
When trying to run test I am getting error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: Migration V1.0.1__create_authorities_table.sql failed
-----------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 90057
Error Code : 90057
Message    : Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (USERNAME)" not found; SQL statement:
```

So it says that Flyway can't build it.
I have only two sql files:
`V1.0.0__create_user_table.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    username            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password        VARCHAR(68) NOT NULL,
    enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

and `V1.0.1__create_authorities_table.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE authorities (
                             username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                             authority VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                             FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

I see that Flyway doesn't like `FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username)` so I also tried with `ALTER TABLE authorities ADD FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username)` but still doesn't work. I checked that when I just remove adding `FOREIGN KEY` then tests are green - no errors.

Seems like both ways from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515905/4952262 are failing for me - what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referential constraints may reference only unique sets of columns, a primary key or unique constraint on them is required, so you need to create a unique constraint on `users(username)` to allow references to this column from referential constraints.

You can simply add an inline constraint to definition of this column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    …
    username            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    …
```

---

It will be better to remove `username` column from `authorities` table and add something like `user_id BIGINT REFERENCES users(id)` instead of it, however, duplication of long values between tables isn't a good practice.